# Is it possible to have global configuration values for a webspace in sulu CMS?

Tags: sulu

is there a way to have (kind of wordpress style) some global configuration values in sulu per webspace?

Reason is, that our SEO guys would like the page title after a | in the meta title on every page, but I would like to share the template accross multiple webspaces.

If I could set just a few values different for the webspaces, I could use the as parameters to the template.

Thx a lot!
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is currently no way to manage this in the UI of sulu - we always use twig globals to inject values like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Snippet for this. And use snippet areas / default snippets. To load this snippet and use its data.

http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/cookbook/default-snippets.html

So you could create a settings snippet. With all settings you want and then use the `sulu_snippet_load_by_area` twig extension to load this data after you did select that snippet in the webspace setting for that area.

Comment: ok, I think I will try this solution with a config snippet type.